# Tabular data struts

Tags: struts2, tabular, actioncontext

I tried to capture data from a master-detail form return an JSON object as follows my form is mimilar this http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/creating_a_theme I followed this guide http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/tabular-inputs.html I can capture master data but how i can access to details? the result I get at this moment is

```
{"codigo":"RQ-201000-1210-00001","fecha":"Oct 25, 2012 12:00:00 AM","dreqproductos":[]}
```

my form is:

how i can obtain dreqproductos?

```
<input name="reqproducto.codigo"   />
<input name="reqproducto.fecha"   />

<input name="reqproducto.dreqproductos[1].masterproducto"   />
<input name="reqproducto.dreqproductos[1].cantidad"         />

<input name="reqproducto.dreqproductos[2].masterproducto"   />
<input name="reqproducto.dreqproductos[2].cantidad"         />
```

my class is

```
public class Reqproducto  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Integer id;
     private String codigo;
     private Date fecha;
     private Set dreqproductos = new HashSet(0);
}
```

and

```
public class Dreqproducto  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Integer id;
     private Masterproducto masterproducto;
     private Reqproducto reqproducto;
     private BigDecimal cantidad;
}
```

and my action is

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package actions;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import hibernate.domain.Centrocosto;
import hibernate.domain.Dreqproducto;
import hibernate.domain.Reqproducto;
import hibernate.util.hibernateUtil;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.*;
import model.dao.impl.DaoReqproductoImpl;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
/**
 *
 * @author DEV11
 */
public class ActionReqProducto extends ActionSupport{

    private InputStream inputStream;
    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return inputStream;
    }

    public Reqproducto reqproducto;
    public void setReqproducto(Reqproducto reqproducto) {
        this.reqproducto = reqproducto;
    }

    public String ReqproductoIns() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        //CAPTURA
        String msg = "VOID";
        Session session = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        //Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if (reqproducto.getId() == null) {//INSERTAR
                //CABECERA INSERTAR GERISTRO
                session.save(reqproducto);

                msg = "INSERT ";
            } else {//ACTUALIZAR
                //CABECERA ACTUALIZAR REGISTRO
                String queryString = "from Reqproducto where id = :id";
                Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
                query.setInteger("id", reqproducto.getId());
                session.update(reqproducto);

                msg = "UPDATE ";
            }
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            //session.getTransaction().commit();
            transaction.commit();

            msg += "OK" + reqproducto.getId();//+session.getIdentifier(reqproducto);;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            //e.printStackTrace();
            msg = "ERROR: " + e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            //session.close();
        }

        //RESPUESTA
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        //String json  = "{cabecera:{'id':'"+id+"','codigo':'"+codigo+"','descripcion':'"+descripcion+"','abreviatura':'"+abreviatura+"','visible':'"+visible+"'}, msg:'Devolviendo Resultado via Ajax en \"Español\"'}";
        String json = gson.toJson(this.reqproducto);
        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the collection present before json serialization? What are you using for the serialization? Is it the struts2-json-plugin?

Comment: i'm using gson, can i send mi proyect? i'm using netbeans